# Dynamic picker elements in ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms.I am designing an application in which I want to display a list of pickers in a list view.The vales in the picker should be dynamic.Below is the code I have written.I struck at writing a List of Picker items in a List.Please anyone help me.Sorry for my English.Thanks in advance.

```
        <ListView x:Name="WindowsList" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding KitchenWindowsList}"
                              HeightRequest="300" IsVisible="{Binding KitchenVisibility}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding KitchenWindowName}" TextColor="#ece6dd" FontAttributes="Bold">
                    <Label.FontSize>
                      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>
                          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="15" Android="15" WinPhone="15" />
                        </OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="20" Android="20" WinPhone="20" />
                        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                      </OnIdiom>
                    </Label.FontSize>
                  </Label>
                  <Picker x:Name="CurtainTypePicker" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeList}" Title="Choose Curtain" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Picker.HeightRequest>
                      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="40"/>
                        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>
                          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="45"/>
                        </OnIdiom.Phone>
                      </OnIdiom>
                    </Picker.HeightRequest>
                 </Picker>
                </Grid>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>              
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Without the viewmodel behind this XAML code it's hard to get an indication of what could be going wrong. Also, you should probably provide a description of what behavior happens when you say that it doesn't work and any error messages that occur.

Comment: Did you raise the property change event in your ViewCell BindingContext?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I solved the issue by Binding ItemSource of Picker and getting data from View model as a lis.